# Python cx_Oracle SQL with bind string variable

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I have a problem with creating SQL query for Oracle database using Python.
I want to bind string variable and it does not work, could you tell me what am I doing wrong? 
This is my code:

```
import cx_Oracle

dokList = []

def LoadDatabase():
    conn = None
    cursor = None
    try:
        conn = cx_Oracle.connect("login", "password", "localhost")

        cursor = conn.cursor()

        query = "SELECT * FROM DOCUMENT WHERE DOC = :param"

        for doknumber in dokList:

            cursor.execute(query, {'doknr':doknumber})
            print(cursor.rowcount)

    except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as err:
        print(err)
    finally:
        if cursor:
            cursor.close()
        if conn:
            conn.close()

def CheckData():

    with open('changedNamed.txt') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

        for line in lines:
            dokList.append(line)

CheckData()
LoadDatabase()
```

The output of `cursor.rowcount` is 0 but it should be number greater than 0.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a dictionary (`{'doknr' : doknumber}`) for your parameter, so it's a **named parameter** - the `:param` [needs to match the key name](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/prez-python-queries-101587.html). Try this:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM DOCUMENT WHERE DOC = :doknr"
for doknumber in dokList:
        cursor.execute(query, {'doknr':doknumber})
        print(cursor.rowcount)
```

For future troubleshooting, to check whether your parameter is getting passed properly, you can also try changing your query to `"select :param from dual"`.

Comment: Okay, I changed it but again the value of `cursor.rowcount` is still 0, and `select :doknr from dual` also didn't work...

Comment: rowcount would be for DML.  For queries, use a SELECT COUNT to get the number of rows.